# Why my Reactstrap's Media object is not aligned properly?

Tags: reactjs, media, reactstrap

I have recently started learning to react and reactstrap and I wanted to use [Reactstrap's Media Object](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/media/) but my results are not what I want. As shown in [documentation](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/media/), the image heading and description should come right next to the image, but after applying the same, the image heading and description are aligned below the image.
[Screenshot of my code's outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0QN8.png).

Code:-

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Media} from "reactstrap";

class Menu extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  dishes: [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: "Uthappizza",
      image: "assets/images/uthappizza.png",
      category: "mains",
      label: "Hot",
      price: "4.99",
      description:
        "A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer."
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Zucchipakoda",
      image: "assets/images/zucchipakoda.png",
      category: "appetizer",
      label: "",
      price: "1.99",
      description:
        "Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Vadonut",
      image: "assets/images/vadonut.png",
      category: "appetizer",
      label: "New",
      price: "1.99",
      description:
        "A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "ElaiCheese Cake",
      image: "assets/images/elaicheesecake.png",
      category: "dessert",
      label: "",
      price: "2.99",
      description:
        "A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms"
    }
  ],
};
}

render() {
const menu = this.state.dishes.map((dish) => {
  return (
    <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 mt-5">
      <Media>
        <Media left middle>
          <Media object src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
        </Media>
        <Media body className="ml-5">
          <Media heading>
          {dish.name}
          </Media>
          {dish.description}
        </Media>
      </Media>
    </div>
  );
});

return (
  <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
      <Media list>{menu}</Media>
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
}

export default Menu;
```

Why my image heading and description are not aligned right to the image? Where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and couldn't find any error in the code. I modified the code as follows:

```js
return (
  <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 mt-5">
    <Media tag="ul" className="row">
      <Media left middle className="col-3">
        <Media object src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
      </Media>
      <Media body className="ml-5 col-9">
        <Media heading>{dish.name}</Media>
        <p>{dish.description}</p>
      </Media>
    </Media>
  </div>
);
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, I solved the problem.

**We have to use "row" and "col-9" to let the descriptions and the images in one row.**

Nevertheless, I am still a little confused: if the class="media-left" lets the image float to the left, why it doesn't work in this situation?

Acknowledgements @rmlockerd and Chaminie

```
return (
  <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 mt-5">
    <Media tag="ul" className="row">
      <Media left middle className="col-3">
        <Media object src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
      </Media>
      <Media body className="ml-5 col-9">
        <Media heading>{dish.name}</Media>
        <p>{dish.description}</p>
      </Media>
    </Media>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably are using bootstrap 5, which does not include the object Media anymore. See [the bootstrap 5 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#media-object). I had the same problem. Try install the bootstrap 4 instead.

Anyway, I just did the downgrade of the bootstrap package to version 4.6.0 and everything is working properly here.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
 render(){
        const menu = this.state.dishes.map((dish) => {
            return (
                <div key={dish.id} className='col-12 mt-5'>
                    <div className='d-flex align-items-center'>
                        <div className='flex-shrink-1'>
                            <img src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                        </div>
                        <div className='flex-grow-1 ms-5'>
                            <h2 className='mt-0'>{dish.name}</h2>
                            <p>{dish.description}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        });

        return (
            <Container>
                <row>
                    <div>
                        {menu}
                    </div>
                </row>
            </Container>
        );
    }
```